# C# Bilinear interpolation RGB

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm trying to implement Bilinear Interpolation in C# using RGB values.

But for the RGB values, I get most of the time values bigger than 255, which breaks the algorithm.

This is my code:

```
public static void ResizeImageBilinear(Color[,] inputImage, double scale)
{
    int maxWidth = (int)(scale * inputImage.GetLength(0));
    int maxHeight = (int)(scale * inputImage.GetLength(1));

    var scaledImage = new Color[maxWidth, maxHeight];

    for (int x = 0; x < scaledImage.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < scaledImage.GetLength(1) - 1; y++)
        {
            //Gets current pixel.
            double xDouble = (x / scale);
            double yDouble = (y / scale);

            int xInOriginal = (int)(Math.Floor(x / scale));
            int yInOriginal = (int)(Math.Floor(y / scale));

            double deltaR = xDouble - xInOriginal;
            double deltaC = yDouble - yInOriginal;

            Console.WriteLine(yInOriginal + " " + yDouble); 

            Color pixel = inputImage[xInOriginal, yInOriginal];
            Color pixelN1 = inputImage[xInOriginal + 1, yInOriginal];
            Color pixelN2 = inputImage[xInOriginal + 1, yInOriginal + 1];
            Color pixelN3 = inputImage[xInOriginal, yInOriginal + 1];

            var red = (int)(Math.Round(
                            pixel.R * (1 - deltaR) * (1 * deltaC) +
                            pixelN1.R * deltaR * (1 - deltaC) +
                            pixelN3.R * (1 - deltaR) * deltaC +
                            pixelN2.R * deltaR * deltaC));

            var blue = (int)(Math.Round(pixel.B * (1 - deltaR) * (1 * deltaC) +
                            pixelN1.B * deltaR * (1 - deltaC) +
                            pixelN3.B * (1 - deltaR) * deltaC +
                            pixelN2.B * deltaR * deltaC));

            var green = (int)(Math.Round(pixel.G * (1 - deltaR) * (1 * deltaC) +
                            pixelN1.G * deltaR * (1 - deltaC) +
                            pixelN3.G * (1 - deltaR) * deltaC +
                            pixelN2.G * deltaR * deltaC));

            Console.WriteLine(red + " " + green + " " + blue);

            //Sets pixel in new image
            scaledImage[x, y] = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
        }
    }

    DrawImage(scaledImage);
}
```

Could anyone help me out finding the issue with the algorithm?

Comment: Algorithm aside... you realize you are processing your image pixel column per pixel column? Quite bizarre, given that images are always saved in rows.

Comment: Is your problem the `1 * deltaC` in `pixel.R * (1 - deltaR) * (1 * deltaC)` - I would imagine this should be `1 - deltaC`. This potential error being repeated in each colour component.

Comment: @Sander correct your result using `Value = pixel.R * (1 - deltaR) * (1 - deltaC) + pixelN1.R * deltaR * (1 - deltaC) + pixelN3.R * (1 - deltaR) * deltaC + pixelN2.R * deltaR * deltaC`

Comment: Also:After getting advice do report back!

Comment: @Chris That worked!